Accessing WooCommerce classes in custom extension
I'm trying to build a custom WooCommerce extension. I followed the developer documentation and used the CLI to create the boilerplate code for a WooCommerce extension. Next I used wp-env to run the extension in a containerized Worpress instance.
My question is I wanted to extend a core class (prefixed with WC_XXXX_XXX ) within my extension but when executed it gives an error saying that the WC_XXXX_XXX class could not be found. If it helps in the error it shows the WC_XXXX_XXX class path as if the class is within my extension directory but actually its not (since the WC_XXXX_XXX class is a WooCommerce core class).
Is there a way to access WC_ classes within my extension as mentioned in certain samples in the DEV doc? or is there some other way?

I tried setting up the same plugin/extension code in a server such as XAMPP (where wordpress and woocommerce had been setup) and the issue doesn't seem to appear.
